# What's wrong with my RPC config?

Tags: node, public-node, config, octez

What does this config miss in order to present the RPC service properly at X.X.X.X

```
    "p2p": {
        "bootstrap-peers": [
            "boot.tzbeta.net",
            "boot.mainnet.oxheadhosted.com"
        ],
        "listen-addr": "[::]:9732"
    },
    "rpc": {
        "cors-origin": [
            "*"
        ],
        "cors-headers": [
            "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Range, GET, POST"
        ],
        "listen-addrs": [
            "X.X.X.X:8732"
        ],
        "acl": [
            {
                "address": "X.X.X.X:8732",
                "whitelist": [
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*/context/**",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*/hash",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*/header",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*/header/**",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*/helpers/current_level",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*/live_blocks",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*/metadata",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*/metadata_hash",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*/minimal_valid_time",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*/operation_hashes",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*/operation_hashes/**",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*/operation_metadata_hash",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*/operations",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*/operations/**",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*/operations_metadata_hash",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*/protocols",
                    "GET/chains/*/blocks/*/votes/**",
                    "GET/chains/*/chain_id",
                    "GET/chains/*/checkpoint",
                    "GET/chains/*/invalid_blocks",
                    "GET/chains/*/invalid_blocks/*",
                    "GET/chains/*/is_bootstrapped",
                    "GET/chains/*/mempool/filter",
                    "GET/chains/*/mempool/monitor_operations",
                    "GET/chains/*/mempool/pending_operations",
                    "GET/config/network/user_activated_protocol_overrides",
                    "GET/config/network/user_activated_upgrades",
                    "GET/config/network/dal",
                    "GET/describe/**",
                    "GET/errors",
                    "GET/monitor/**",
                    "GET/network/greylist/ips",
                    "GET/network/greylist/peers",
                    "GET/network/self",
                    "GET/network/self",
                    "GET/network/stat",
                    "GET/network/version",
                    "GET/network/versions",
                    "GET/protocols",
                    "GET/protocols/*",
                    "GET/protocols/*/environment",
                    "GET/version",
                    "POST/chains/*/blocks/*/context/contracts/*/big_map_get",
                    "POST/injection/operation"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I don't have the port specified in the acl address. Are you getting any response from this config?